# Question on Block Maxima Method for Extreme Value Theory

Tags: extreme-value-analysis

I am reading about extreme value theory. Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be i.i.d. random variables and $M_n = \text{max}\{X_1,...,X_n\}$ as usual.
I understand that, by the Fisher-Tippett-Gnedenko theorem:
If there exist sequences $b_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a_n > 0$ s.t.

$$\frac{M_n - b_n}{a_n} \xrightarrow{d} G,$$

for some distribution function, then $G$ is a Generalised Extreme Value (GEV) distribution, i.e. belongs to the Gumbel, Frechet or Weibull family.

In a later chapter about the block maxima, there is the following statement in these [notes extreme value theory (german, sorry!)](https://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/Stochastik/skript_extremwerttheorie.pdf): *"We model the distribution of the maxima through a GEV distribution. Of course, for the convergence normalising constants are needed, but in our case, we can assume that these are already part of the parameters $\mu, \sigma, \gamma$ (which are the location / scale / shape parameters of the GEV distribution."*

This last sentence confused me. Does that hold in general? If yes, why? If not, which assumptions are neccessary?

Any hints appreciated. Thank you very much!

P.S. Like I said, I am referring to these [notes on extreme value theory](https://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/Stochastik/skript_extremwerttheorie.pdf). It's German, sorry! (Remark 6.1.2) But the same statement can also be found here on [these slides](https://www2.meteo.uni-bonn.de/projekte/SPPMeteo/wiki/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=cops_2a&cache=cache&media=evt_cops2.pdf), for example (page 4).

Answer (score 1):

This would be better as a comment but I don't have enough reputation: $a_n$ functions as a shift parameter and $b_n$ as a scale parameter, which is analogous to $\mu$ and $\sigma$. If you have a variable $X_n$ which is centred at $5$, you can shift it to be located at zero using $b_n=5$, alternatively you can set $\mu=5$, likewise for the scale.